# How to shift 32 bit int by 32 (yet again)

Tags: java, c++, c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

Ok, so I know that typically left- and right- shifts are well defined only for values `0..31`. I was thinking how to best extend this to include 32, which simplifies some algorithms. I came up with:

```
 int32 << n & (n-32) >> 5
```

Which seems to work. Question is, is it guaranteed to work on any architecture (C, C++, Java), and can it be done more effectively?

Comment: Have you considered shifting by 32, then shifting for the remaining places?

Comment: It actually does include 32. Only more than 32 is not defined.

Comment: Java specs mentions it uses only lower 5 bits of the righ-hand operand if left hand operand is 32bit,, and I believe the same is true for ANSI C.

Comment: What is the intended result? All this gives you is zero once you correct the operator precedence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java it's guaranteed to work if those variables are of type `int`, since `>>` in Java does an arithmetic right shift and shifting more than 31 also has defined behavior. But beware of operator precedence

```
int lshift(int x, int n)
{
    return (x << n) & ((n-32) >> 5);
}
```

This will work for shift count **up to 32**. But it can be modified to include any int values with shift counts larger than 31 return 0

```
return (x << n) & ((n-32) >> 31);
```

However in C and C++ the size of `int` type and the behavior of `>>` operator is [implementation defined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8422424/995714). Most (if not all) *modern* implementations implement it as arithmetic shift for signed types though. Besides, the behavior of shifting more than the variable width is [undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7401888/995714). Worse yet, signed overflow invokes UB so even a left shift by 31 is also UB ([until C++14](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26331035/995714)). Therefore to get a well defined output you need to

- Use a unsigned fixed-width type like `uint32_t` (so `x << 31` isn't UB)
- Use a compiler that emits arithmetic right shift instruction for `>>` and use a signed type for `n`, or implement the arithmetic shift yourself
- Mask the shift amount to limit it to 5 bits for `int32_t`

The result would be

```c
uint32_t lshift(uint32_t x, int32_t n)
{
    return (x << (n & 0x1F)) & ((n-32) >> 31);
}
```

If the architecture supports [conditional instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26154488/995714) like x86 or ARM then the following way may be faster

```c
return n < 32 ? x << n : 0;
```

On a 64-bit platform you can made this even simpler by shifting in a 64-bit type and then mask. Some 32-bit platforms like ARM does support shifting by 32 so this method is also efficient

```c
return ((uint64_t)x << (n & 0x3F)) & 0xFFFFFFFFU;
```

You can see the output assembly [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tQVvQAZPLUwA5YwCNMxLgHZSAB1QLC62nsMTQS8fNTorG3sjJxdOdyUVMNoGAmZiAgDjU05FZUxVPxS0ggi7R2c3RVT0zKCchWqS6zLoiriASkVUA2JkDgByKQBma2RDLABqcSGdZAb8emnscQAGAEFVtYNrAiHJAH0CCdYFBDwqAght%2Bj3DiYAPUgnr3YOj2nbN8VdZdYn/ibETAEHq0CYQe5TGbTHQTD5TSQANnBEFoAFo9u0ocshtgJkNOJ8hr8Nq4ACJfdYvW5HE5nC6SK47GkPJ7Ut5wz7rb4kgGA4GguFQ2F7KEAMQewphQpAExW0xJ3wp3KpzI5dPOuyZNw5j2earuHy%2BP02fKBIOIYKgL0R3EO7UhMOlqIRyJW9yGYvaWKkbvuYoDgYDAFUFcblWt%2Bp1WCB%2BgBWfqkUz9FaJ1CxnRyOQTBTdXqYBEExMEWOp72kADWXERADoAJyuTiSVx1oauIZDREADh4vBj/W4iaMXBWKyTpbTscTChAY5LKajpDgsBgiBQqCMHjw7DIFAgaE324qwE4K0kpCo24IzhnEAcE9IDmsaQAnrHOImD0YtAQAPK0Vg3wXUgsCMERgHYB98CBAoADdMBnYDMHufIDGvd9Ex2ZQH1YPAHGIV89CwDDSAIYg8GHfoP06Gh6CYNgOB4fgQHPYRRBQLMZCEPCZ0gTpUA8JJELRX9JAmNEAHU2FYcSqHg4gHG8TA0WYBQjGnPICg0CBzFqbJSHMUoohiYJvF8Og9NM0I/CM8pYlyRJCkaSz6k0pIinSWzWnshpihcqpii8kzCS6Ho%2Bi4aNYwTcdgPTfp7i7RE0VtCZgGQZAJlPGsxIgXBCBIQscgmPRDx3QtJCxTMZDkYsJ06CAkAPLcd3ISgmqPFwTzPC8rxvSh72Ap9aFfEivx/f9AKgzAwNESDgOg/I1HgxDUwMlDkDQgYP3IehsOA3D8MIjAtuLcjKOoi86EYFhIKYgQ%2B3Ajjqq4g7eIgfjBL8YTRPEqTWBkjTHO03T9CyMxtCCtpPDMpJ/JCczaEhny3KcvzQbqBzFtRzzmmMqHfJqdH9IJppIjsiLQvzCn%2B2i5NVrihKkpStKMqynK8qIYhCqeErmucQtuEqzjpFqhd6sajc%2Bd3NrJY6kA8HSyQz04Tg6x61hr2IW8BtWoaRqoz8N2/egJqA1bQPAubzbwGCloQh9kNQ9CDZ269%2B1Wg6COIF8iJO0izowmirvo27eAEHI2LEYXuIcN6PqE2MRLEyTpNk%2BTFKUFS1MBrHge0fzDNx8mcnh2GiashGkcEBJc%2BSZzy9coG68CovvOr%2BvAmJxoq5C3MwsYyL40TOnJ3ixLku4CYFYyyROBrOe63BDmCuGIreY6wqheekXSLqzoEEwZgsBcd7KxADtspWIY6xWbhJG4RFJEka%2BuzjIRY0HUhhzjMcR9IOLpwsV3mLJcq4GrrlKs4Vq%2B5ZY7hAGkIwtpgBdiVurTW2sHx629qNI240AJm0TBbWaAxra2zwMtB261NokSwu7RMnsjrERdmRCigdLp0RuoxMO58hCPQkNvGOcd/6fToN9ZOf0ZJojks4DOylVLqUxlpUwOl84NwMhDVuwVobWQsmo0uNlNH4xRnQDyGQ1E1yUaYnuAVCad3bi3Mmbde55nCiFGmw8HxxTWAAJQALLM3ShMLs2Ul74E5tzYqsD%2BbDCGFvWQMhRZliXBLSB0sYGpPgcQIwdZZ5oL6neTBz5sEuzGibfBU0ZoQRIYQm2WMKFISoc7batCcJ4S9j7Y6JEWHnUXLRa6DEuDcLfpHJ68T5CvXgPHL6icfop3%2BjnJRmhVF2JyIXRxWj9G6JWdoyuhjkZN1Mf5Cx7lu57PsbYsG9RTnrLaJ0PuVM3FRQ8bFWMPjfGpUCXWbK89wS0DoJgLEuUwkr2fmvKJXNhhxjiTVYBSTwHtRanuBFFQxjgRVqOPJWt%2BqFOGsU7apS/zlPmtNS21SQK1LgvbBpTs/YtP2m0xhftulsL6SHLhzFES8PYvwsZgjJnCITv0JOv1U5oiMHsBZSQlm6DUWsloGyYZ%2BDhoq8IZzG610OeY4xzccY3J8h3S5NjSbytuZTVxg9aaeNjIzCeExUWiEynPFYNYVihPyhC0FPNwWFkRNChJsKoz70PsfSgg9P7f1/la/ogCcjzjLJ0KsXYhguskF2VwStH6IkRASV%2B79%2BhDGefTKcAbyz9kkIW0eiTA2kHkj4DQ3AgA%3D). I don't see how it can be improved further